# Is there a weather regions map of United States?

Tags: weather, weather-api

In order to give a better targeting in the product we need to know the wether condition in the user location. I dont want to query for each user location. I want to query by regions, so for Manhattan for example i will do one weather query and not for each user in Manhattan. Is there a map that divide United Stated to weather regions or a site that return weather conditions and the polygon for this weather, so i will not need to query again for this polygon if i already query for it for another user that exist in the same region?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/regional_monitoring/usa.shtml) what you were looking for?

Comment: There is a colorize (by regions) maps there , but i don't see a geo definition (by polygon or coordinate) of these regions.